# Is there any GUI mode for omxplayer?

Tags: omxplayer

Currently I have to use terminal for media control keys while playing any video via omxplayer. However I am setting up this for a friend and he is not that comfortable with terminal.

- Is there any way I can enable GUI mode with omxplayer?
- Or any extra extension/package which gives GUI controls to omxplayer?

Comment: To use GUI he will need to connect the Pi to a screen but obviously you have a screen connected since you playing videos.

Comment: I meant GUI controls. omxplayer can be used only via terminal

Answer (score 2):

[tboplayer](https://github.com/KenT2/tboplayer) seems like what you looking for.

`omxplayer` itself is just the engine to read and display video. `tboplayer` is an interface someone built.  It starts `omxplayer` in the console (hidden, you cant see it) and then just relays all the commands to omxplayer via this nice python GUI.  It plays audio too :)

[image]

Then just create a short cut to the python script, on the LXDE desktop and he can start it when ever he needs too.

Answer (score 2):

Along with `tboplayer`, I also found omxplayerGUI which is built using Python ans TKinter.

thread on raspberry pi forums [link](http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=40860)
and user manual [link](http://steinerdatenbank.de/software/omxplayerGUI_manual.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

There is another web GUI for omxplayer from myself called `omxwebgui` written in PHP. It's free and easy to use -> https://github.com/brainfoolong/omxwebgui

Answer (score 1):

there is OMXPLayerGUI, a front end omxplayer with GUI.
just add the repository and gpg-key and apt-get update, and apt-get install.
you are done!

or go to this blog cubepi.blogspot.co.id, this guy create an image with raspbian jessie, it includes OMXPlayerGUI and LibreOffice and other stuff.

enough custom for everyday computing with your raspberry PI.

**cubepi.blogspot.co.id**

cheers...

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a simple gui for the OmxPlayer in C#.Net for the Raspberry Pi. You can either use buttons to control it or press keys similar to omxplayer. Here's the location to download the source code/binary as well as installation instructions.

http://russellhankins.com/Blog/Raspberry%20Pi/OmxPlayerGui/